# Making a repeated alarm stop during a phone call

Tags: java, android, eclipse, alarmmanager

My app has a repeating alarm with a number picker, so if i chose to repeat every one minute a sound goes off every one minute, but if the user received a phone call the alarm doesn't stop. How can i solve this problem? What should i implement in the receiver activity in order for it to detect a phone call?

Receiver:

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class MainReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



         @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

             MediaPlayer m=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound2);
             m.start();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Honestly I did not understand your question at all. But if you just need to know the call state in your receiver, then you can always use TelephonyManager getCallState() API. Documentation link is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCallState().

Comment: @vicky my application does a repeating alarm at the chosen minutes even after the app is closed, and when the user receives a phone call from someone the alarm doesn't stop and it bothers the user since the sound keeps going on and on, so i was wondering if there's a code with an if and else statement so if there's a call the alarm will stop and when there isn't the alarm goes off normally.

Comment: As per Android documentation for AlarmManager.setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation), it will continue to come until called explicitly. If you are using this API then either you have to cancel it on call or in your receiver you have to add call condition and just return without doing anything.

Comment: @vicky yeah that's exactly what i'm using, so i should use getCallState() ?

Comment: @T-Chen i'll look into that thanks!

Comment: Just updated my above answer a bit:As per Android documentation for AlarmManager.setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation), it will continue to come until explicitly removed with cancel(PendingIntent). If you are using this API then either you have to cancel it on call or in your receiver you have to add call condition and just return without doing anything.

Comment: @vicky how do i do that? it's in the comment section not the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just updated my above answer a bit:As per Android documentation for AlarmManager.setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation), it will continue to come until explicitly removed with cancel(PendingIntent). If you are using this API then either you have to cancel it on call or in your receiver you have to add call condition and just return without doing anything.

Comment: i still have a bit of a problem with implementing the call condition thing. i found this example http://www.javatpoint.com/android-call-state-broadcastreceiver-example but it's not working, could you possibly help me?

Comment: @markos: Still ur stuck or got out of it ?? Let me know if I can help

Comment: well in the link i provided i still didn't know where the problem in the code is, so if you  could possibly take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

> try code:
>
> ```
>         final MediaPlayer m = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound2);
>         m.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
>                 m.start();
>             }
>         });
>
>         AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
>         am.requestAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
>                 Log.i("FOCUS",focusChange + "");
>                 if (focusChange > 0)
>                     m.start();
>                 else
>                     m.pause();
>             }
>         }, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
> ```

Or make your BroadcastReceiver receiver phone incoming state:

```
public class MainReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String PLAYAUDIO = "PLAYAUDIO";
    private static final String PHONE_STATE = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static MediaPlayer m;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(PLAYAUDIO)) {
            m= MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound2);
            m.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    m.start();
                }
            });
            m.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    m = null;
                }
            });
        } else
            if (intent.getAction().equals(PHONE_STATE)) {// NEW CALL STATE
                String extra = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (extra.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) 
                                     && m != null)
                     m.start();
                else if (m != null)
                     m.pause();
            }

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
    <receiver android:name="YourPackage.MainReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="PLAYAUDIO"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    //Add permistion
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: in the Log.i("FOCUS",focusChange); it says The method i(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Comment: thank you so much for your time! in the " switch (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE))" part it gave me an error that tells me to switch to JRE or something and once i switched the "case TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE: //Call end" part says "case expressions must be constant expressions"

Comment: the first error was "Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted"

Comment: iv'e tried this one also and it shows no errors but the sound doesn't go off.

Comment: try{  
  String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);  if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){      
              }    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){     
              }  
if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){  
                   Toast.makeText(context, "it's working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                   MediaPlayer m=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound2);
                   m.start();
              }
          }  catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

Answer (score 0):

Guys i finally figured it out, i saw couple of examples of telephonymanager and i wrote this one out and worked fine.

```
public class MainReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{        

@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    MediaPlayer m=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound2);

                TelephonyManager tm = 

                    (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);                        

                switch (tm.getCallState()) {

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                        m.stop();
                        break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:                                


                        m.stop();
                                break;


                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:                                


                             m.start();

                            break;

                } 

        }

}
```